# unable to edit nested gridview , giving error Additional information: Syntax error: Missing operand after 'fa9bb79' operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

getting error while binding child grid view . errro - missing operand after 'fa9bb79' operator. while clicking parent table it should bind child table values which is not happening. im getting error in this particular line - ""

```
DataRow[] gvChildRows = dtChildTable.Select("uid = " + empId);//2fa9bb79-7d0b-4e38-853c-d275d5d634c2
```

Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvParent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvParent_RowDataBound"
CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" ShowHeader="True" DataKeyNames="uniqueid">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="img1" ImageUrl="img/Collapse.GIF" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee Id" DataField="ToAddress">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="160px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee Name" DataField="PODate">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="160px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Designation" DataField="PoNo">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="160px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmpName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit1" Text="</td><tr id='trCollapseGrid' style='display:none' ><td colspan='5'>" />
            <asp:GridView ID="gvChild" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"
                DataKeyNames="uid" ForeColor="#333333" PageSize="2" AllowPaging="True"
                OnPageIndexChanging="gvChild_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvChild_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowDeleting="gvChild_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvChild_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvChild_RowUpdating">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Skill ID" DataField="uid" ReadOnly="True">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee Id" DataField="Comments" ReadOnly="True">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PartNo">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("PartNo")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditSkillSet" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("Qty")%>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("unitprice")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditRemarks" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("unitprice")%>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" EditText="Edit" HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="true" />
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" DeleteText="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
                </Columns>
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>


private void BindChildgvwChildView(string empId, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView gvChild)
{
    DataTable dtChildTable = GetChildTableData();
    DataTable dtCloneChildTable = dtChildTable.Clone();


    DataRow[] gvChildRows = dtChildTable.Select("uid = " + empId);//2fa9bb79-7d0b-4e38-853c-d275d5d634c2
   // DataRow[] gvChildRows = dtChildTable.Select("uid = " + empId);


   // 2FA9BB79-7D0B-4E38-853C-D275D5D634C2
    foreach (DataRow gvChildRow in gvChildRows)
    {
        dtCloneChildTable.ImportRow(gvChildRow);
    }
    gvChild.DataSource = dtCloneChildTable;
    gvChild.DataBind();
}
```